# Rigid body not stop at Platform unity engine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i use rigidbody2d to move platform

also my player use rigidbody2d for controlle

the problem is when player jump into platform his cant stay on it (sliding)

my code is

```
if (inHelecopter)
    {
        player.transform.SetParent(helecopter.transform,false);
    }
    else
    {
        player.transform.parent = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about making it so that rather than parenting the player transform, move the player object depending on how the position of the platform has changed in the last frame?

```
if (carryingPlayer)
{
    player.transform.position += lastPosition - transform.position;
}
lastPosition = transform.position;
```